# Flutter - Loading/Progress Indicator inside TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField like so:

```
TextFormField(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
          errorMaxLines: 2,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        autocorrect: false,
        onChanged: (_) {},
        validator: (_) {},
      ),
```

This TextFormField will fetch an email from an api whenever **onChanged()** is called, so I decided I want to put a progress/loading indicator inside to indicate that it is fetching data, but I am having a hard time figuring out implementing it.

So is there a way I can insert a **CircularProgressIndicator()** or a simple progress/loading indicator inside a TextFormField?

Something like this:

[image: TextFormField with Loading indicator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props to [@stefanodecillis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5937508/stefanodecillis), I was also able to achieve it using [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                      errorMaxLines: 2,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    autocorrect: false,
                    onChanged: (_) {},
                    validator: (_) {},
                  ),
                  (state.isSubmitting)
                      ? Positioned(
                          top: 5,
                          right: 5,
                          child: Container(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 5):

TextFormEdit doesn't have the right attribute, that is Suffix widget.
Still, InputDecoration has the **Suffix** attribute where you can append whatever progress widget you want.
Once here, you can keep it visible or not (and a bunch of other settings) directly in the widget.

```
TextFormField(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
          suffix: isLoading?CircularProgressIndicator():null
          errorMaxLines: 2,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        autocorrect: false,
        onChanged: (_) {},
        validator: (_) {},
      ),
```

Comment: I see, I took all my time looking at TextFormEdit attributes finding the right one for this usecase. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Before loading add this variable to class statefull widget

```
bool _isLoading = true;
```

so when your email loaded

```
setState(){
   _isLoading = false;
}
```

and for add this text field code

```
TextFormField(
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
            suffix: isLoading?CircularProgressIndicator():null,
              errorMaxLines: 2,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            autocorrect: false,
            onChanged: (_) {},
            validator: (_) {},
          ),
```

Comment: I am tempted to do it this way, and this does seem to work but is there a way to put it centerRight inside textformfield?

Comment: you need both icons email and loading?? or just one of them?